# Wpf Настройка ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В моем примере у каждого TextBox есть свой ScrollViewer, при листинге TextBox когда ScrollViewer достигает конца, активируется внешний ScrollViewer и листается абсолютно всё. Мне нужно чтобы при листинге TextBox, не активировался внешний ScrollViewer.

Код который воспроизводит проблему, заранее спасибо.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border x:Name="GroupPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>

            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
            <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,14,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"    AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>

                    <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>

                    <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>

                    <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>

                    <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А зачем тогда внешний скролл, если вы не хотите, чтобы он работал? Вообще, вложеный скролл - это плохая история с точки зрения UX, я бы рекомендовал избавиться от одного их двух совсем.

Comment: @aepot у меня есть страница в ней много контента, кнопки, поля и прочее. В текстовых полях я указываю ScrollViewer вертикальный. Когда у текстового поля появляется скролл, то при достижении прокрутки вниз текстового поля, скролл для страницы активируется и листает все. Если вы создадите проект с моим примером, вы поймёте сразу в чем проблема. Избавиться от скролов для поля и страницы плохая идея, очень плохая идея. Как мне листать страницу, также как мне листать текст в текстовом поле.

Comment: Уберите скролл на текстовых полях, есть де внешний скролл, чтобы их прокручивать, верно? Либо разбейте на страницы/табы, ещё что-то придумайте. Здесь проблема не поведении прокрутки, а в том что в целом решение неудачное.

Comment: @aepot внешний скролл прокручивает страницу, а не контент внутри элементов. Если убрать скролл у поля, я не смогу листать его содержимое. Думаю вы не поняли суть проблемы.

Comment: Двойной скролл - суть проблемы. Я всего-лишь предлагаю поискать другое решение, а не втыкать костыли в прокрутку. Это по-первых нетривиальная задача, вот-вторых мне как пользователю было бы непонятно, почему скролл есть, но не прокрычивается (мышка сдохла?). То есть вы намеренно хотите внедрить UX-баг в приложение. Подумайте ещё раз.

Comment: @aepot "Плохая история с точки зрения UX" которая используется повсеместно, даже далеко ходить не надо, комментарий вот пишу, если он длинный, появляется скрол у текстового поля, или вон ответ, если длинный, то у поля появляется скрол, что, плохое решение? Да ну, бросьте, такое решение есть везде, и все к этому привыкли, всем нравиться. Ну а человек хочет поведения как тут, на SO, когда скрол у текстового поля дошел до конца, внешний скрол (скрол страницы) не прокручивался (как это делает WPF) пока не убрать курсор с текстового поля или пока не уберется скрол у поля.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ покрутите код вверху в вопросе, когда докрутили до низу, что происходит? Скроллится страница, верно? Так вот, автор хочет, чтобы не скроллилась. Убедитесь, что вы верно поняли вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Не знаю как у вас, но у меня там есть ограничение, если я кручу быстро и не останавливаюсь, то внешний скрол не работает, а если я сделаю паузу и начну опять крутить код, то через некое время "отпустит" и начнет крутить контент. Если я буду крутить находясь за пределами кода, то код вообще не будет крутиться, я "проскочу" его. А теперь сделайте тоже самое в WPF, что будет? Верно, вы сразу, без каких либо задержек начнете крутить основной контент, когда дойдете до конца текстового поля, а если будете крутить страницу и попадете на текстовое поле, начнете крутить его.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну ок, если вы считаете, что подфиксить поведение - достойное решение, предложите ответ. Я бы из десктопного приложения не стал делать "браузер".

Comment: @aepot При чем тут "браузер", по вашему в браузере должно быть одно поведение скрола, в десктоп другое? Какая разница где скролить и что? Да и подобное поведение я много где встречал именно в десктоп приложениях. В любом случае, задача поставлена, ее надо решить, нравиться вам или нет, на то и SO. "предложите ответ" - я сам его ищу, причем уже много лет, ибо самому не нравиться стандартное поведение WPF. Конкретно в данном вопросе человеку наверно будет достаточно останавливать внешний скрол, пока не уберется мышь с внутреннего, но тут я не уверен...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы верно поняли, что мне надо чтобы когда у текстового поля скрол достигал конца контента или начала(не важно) Чтобы основной скрол страницы не крутил контент, это очень не красиво. Единственное решение которое я смог придумать и работает для меня, это обернуть стиль у стиля TextBox ControlTemplate в ScrollViewe, пример кода на измененном TextBox https://pastebin.com/7TzYb9uA Если есть решение лучше, я был бы рад его разобрать.

Comment: @aepot ```Я бы из десктопного приложения не стал делать "браузер"``` таких приложений море, это красиво и оставляет у пользователя положительное впечатление о UX. Также разбирал статью что сейчас во многих приложениях берется что то схожее из браузера, страницы, переходы, тот же DashBoard где у вас меню и при выборе пункта  у вас открывается страница нужная, чем не схожесть с вебом? Это не TabControl уже, другое поведение, другое представление. Хотя пример не лучший. Но вопрос был не об этом. Я прикрепил в комментарии выше свое решение, оно избавляет от проблемы в вопросе.

Comment: Это решение было у меня до создания вопроса, может это не красиво или не правильно. Поэтому я создал вопрос чтобы разобраться в нем. Нагородить костылей я могу всегда, но разобраться и сделать лучше, правильнее. Получить новый опыт или знания не общаясь со специалистами в данной отрасли сложно. Я не учился на эту деятельность-программиста, и ценю ответы, помощь. Без обмена опыта не стать лучше, и не возможно быть опытнее всех, даже если опыт лет в 50, всегда есть тот кто опытнее в чем то.

Comment: Если есть решение, можете оформить его ответом, вдруг кому-то пригодится. Я сейчас сижу в WinUI3 и там такие костыли приходится сознательно городить, что ваше решение - райский сад. :)

Comment: @aepot хорошо оформлю ответ, мало ли на стороннем ресурсе удалится код. И пожалуй создам проектом с примером на стандартных стилях, без dp свойств и изменения поведения.  ```WinUI3``` Не видел, загуглю) Есть отличия от wpf? в двух словах, преимущества какие?)

Comment: @xellan в двух словах это следующая версия после UWP с доступом к Win32 апишкам как в WPF. Тот же XAML, но со своими фокусами. Работает только под Win10 и Win11. Откройте MS Store, найдите приложение WinUI 3 Gallery, установите и посмотрите как там что выглядит. Заодно если будете пробовать, там же и примеры кода и разметки есть. Еще потребуется минимум .NET 6 и Visual Studio 2022, ну и SDK скачать https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Решение которое избавляет от проблем с прокруткой. Когда скрол достигает конца элемента начинается листинг основного скрола, и листается абслолютно всё. Код из вопроса демонстрирует эту проблему.
В примере решения берется стиль `TextBox` и само представление оборачиваем в `ScrollViewer` и задаем вертикальный или горизонтальный скрол. Также указываем `Focusable="False"` чтобы не было фокуса на сам `ScrollViewer` иначе попросту `TextBox` перестанет работать, станет не кликабельным.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="400">
        <Window.Resources>
    
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            </Border>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border x:Name="GroupPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64"   Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
    
                            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,14,64"     AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
    
                            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64"   Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
    
                            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64"   Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
    
                            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                        <Grid Width="300" Background="#F1F1F1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,14,64"   Background="Transparent"   AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
    
                            <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```